# jquery mobile events on android vs. iphone

Tags: jquery, android, ios, jquery-mobile

i´m new with jquery mobile. My problem is that I need to catch the vmousemove events on a div because I need to drag images within this div like the svg images on google maps.

I got a demo on http://demo.baral.de/test/

I got 3 devices: **iphone iOS5**, **Android 3.2 on Samsung tab** and **Android 2.2.2 on HTC desire**. When I "hover" over the green div I thought there would be a lot of "vmousemove" while my finger touches an moves on the display.

The **iphone** fires:

- vmouseover
- vmousedown
- vmousecancel
- a lot of vmousemove
- vmouseup

This seems to be perfect to me

The **Android 3.2** fires:

- vmouseover
- vmousedown
- vmousecancel
- vmousemove

The **Android 2.2.2** fires:

- vmouseover
- vmousedown
- vmousecancel
- vmousemove (1 time)

and after I finished the move and my finger leaves the display it fires

- a lot of vmousemove
- vmouseup

Is this "normal" for jquery mobile? A bug or just the wrong code?

Thanks!

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" data-position="fixed" id="wrapper">
        <div id="test" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: green"></div>
        <div id="footer" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px;">    
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#wrapper").live('pageinit', function() {
            $("#test").bind('vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmousecancel', function (event) {
                $('#footer ul').append("<li>"+event.type+"</li>");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug with jquery-mobile, when you want to achieve something when mouse moves, you can do it anyway as it is getting fired once. It might be by design.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and adding "event.preventDefault()" at the beginning of the callback function solved it. Details of are described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events).

Example:

```
$("#test").bind('vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmousecancel', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $('#footer ul').append("<li>"+event.type+"</li>");
});
```